# Lenovo Yoga 3 14 Keyboard and mouse freezing

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse, touchpad, lenovo

Device Lenovo Yoga 3 14
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Issue:
Keyboard and mouse would freeze up (happened a lot during writing this question).

Mouse would freeze up and not respond (touchpad), jump around the screen as if it had a mind of it's own.

Keyboard would either not work at all (doesn't register key presses, resulting in text such "hll tere") or it would stick to one key (resulting in "hellllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllo there")

I remember running Ubuntu in 16.04 and it had the same issues. I remember that I managed to fix it somehow, but don't remember how. I think, and reading around seems to confirm iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiit, that the issue might be with the touchscreen.

It's happening in terminal, Slack, Skype, Chrome, Firefox, Sublime... hell even playing Solitaire.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

EDIT 2: I permanently disabled my touchscreen.

This is the guide I've used: https://phpocean.com/tutorials/computer-skills/how-to-disable-the-touchscreen-drivers-permanently-on-ubuntu-17-10/63

The guy talks about not ever using the touchscreen and how he was looking for a solution to turn it off permanently.

He offers two solutions, I picked the following:

Edit your: `40-libinput.conf` file:

`sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`

Find the controller for your touchscreen. Something like:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

Change `MatchIsTouchscreen "on"` to `MatchIsTouchscreen "off"` and reboot.

This helped some, but still not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something similar with Yoga

Lenovo Ideapad  320
Problem: Elan Touchpad (and a cursor, of course) randomly freezes, The system (ubuntu 18.04) needs to be rebooted.

My workaround solution (with modprobe) is:

to make 2 scripts- I named them `touchactive.sh` and `touchactive2.sh` 
in `/bin` ( do it with `sudo gedit`...or something)

`touchactive.sh` (that contains this...)

```
#!/bin/bash
modprobe -r elan_i2c
```

(and...)

`touchactive2.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
modprobe elan_i2c[/b]
```

then in terminal:  sudo visudo

you add these lines:

```
vader ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/touchactive.sh
vader ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/touchactive2.sh
```

*vader* is my user name, so you change it with yours...
 ..and save it

open system settings -> keyboard -> "+" -> and create shortcuts with keybinding:

name "Touchpad Elan Restart" 1 with keys <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> 
command: `sudo /bin/touchactive.sh`
and... "Touchpad Elan Restart 2" with keys <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
command: `sudo /bin/touchactive2.sh`

Restart computer

(this is my example you can choose different option and names)

so when all freezes, you can just use keys <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> then <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and your touchpad / cursor restarts without rebooting the whole system.

This is my solution and some relief (not very elegant, though...) so I can work normally until release of a next kernel ( there is some hope...).